# Oracle SQL Inline NOT NULL named constraint

Tags: sql, oracle11g

how can I specify a NOT NULL contraint at the end of my sql statement as I can with a UNIQUE

```
 CREATE TABLE test ( 
        WORKFLOW_CLASS_ID VARCHAR2(24),
        DEPT_OWNER VARCHAR2(3), 
        NAME VARCHAR2(64), 
        PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR2(24), 
        CONSTRAINT WF_WORKFLOW_CLASS_pk PRIMARY KEY (WORKFLOW_CLASS_ID), 
        CONSTRAINT dup_workflow UNIQUE (DEPT_OWNER, NAME), 
        CONSTRAINT not_null NOT NULL(PRODUCT_ID))
```

The above create string is built dynamically using schema defined in an XML document, which defines constraints in its own tag, so therefore **I tack on the contraints at the end** of the sql string.   When I try to specify NOT NULL I get invalid identifier.

EDIT:
Below is the stucture of my xml document.  This file has evolved and over time. I use it to generate DAO and Javabean boilerplate code that I cut and paste into Eclipse and for dynamically creating html forms (xml has field, size and label).  It is also used for an Admin CRUD application for maintaining the backend.  I recently added the `<tableConstraints>` tag because I wanted to add UNIQUE constraints; UNIQUE constraint could be specified at the end of the create statement. In hind sight, I should have added a `<contraint>` tag within my `<column>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE schema PUBLIC "SchemaId" "../../schema.dtd">
<schema>
  <tableName>WF_WORKFLOW_CLASS</tableName>
  <javaBean>WorkflowClass</javaBean>
  <tableAlias>wfc</tableAlias>
  <tableTitle>Workflow process definitions by department</tableTitle>
  <tableConstraints>, CONSTRAINT dup_workflow UNIQUE (DEPT_OWNER, NAME), CONSTRAINT not_null NOT NULL(PRODUCT_ID)</tableConstraints>
  <oneToMany>
        <attName>work_item_list</attName>
        <attName>work_action_list</attName>
  </oneToMany>

  <column>
        <name>WORKFLOW_CLASS_ID</name>
        <type>VARCHAR2</type>
        <size>24</size>
        <label>Work flow Class Unique ID</label>
  </column>

  <primaryKey>      
        <name>WORKFLOW_CLASS_ID</name>
        <type>timestamp</type>
  </primaryKey>

  <foreignKey>
        <name>ADMIN_BY</name>
        <table>EBITPSV.PS_NAMES_V009</table>
        <lookUpKey>badge</lookUpKey>
        <returnField>lname</returnField>
  </foreignKey>

</schema>
```

Comment: you _can't_ create them inline at the end of the table creation. Are you able to do many `alter table add constraint` at the end?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An not null constraint is declared *inline*, after [each individual](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table.php) column name:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( ... 
        NAME VARCHAR2(64), 
        PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR2(24) not null,
        ... )
```

If you wish to [name the constraint explicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2062833) then you also do this after each column:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( ... 
        NAME VARCHAR2(64), 
        PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR2(24)  
         CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_ID_NN NOT NULL,
        ... )
```

You can of course modify the column after the table has been created:

```
ALTER TABLE test
 MODIFY product_id varchar2(24) not null;
```

#### Update:

Judging by your recently posted XML script the best thing to do would be to add a sub-tag `<notNull>` to your `<column>` tag. With 2 values - e.g. `1, 0` you could add a not null constraint in the same way as you decide whether something is a varchar or not.

The other way it would be possible is to loop through the values in your `<tableConstraints>` tag and run multiple [`alter table add constraint ...`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php) or [`alter table modify ...`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#i1015640) after you have created the table.

You suggestion of adding `<constraint>` sub-tag in `<column>` and creating them all at the column level will only work for [single column constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#i1015609) not multiple as you need here.

Comment: sounds like I can't do it the way I can the UNIQUE contraint.  I edited my question with further explaination of why I was trying to declare at the end.

Comment: @jeff, I've updated my answer, including a some links which you may find helpful.

Comment: great suggestions. The <notNull> tag sounds the most promising right now.